# Sencha Touch top tabs icons

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

Can I set tab icons if the tabpanel is docked on top? If it is docked at the bottom the icons are shown but if I dock it to the top they disappear.

Comment: The answer I provided doesn't work because the html content isn't shown. If i change the Panel's layout to fit it looks the same like a bottom docked tabpanel. Any help will be apprecieted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue can be resolved with docked Ext.Panels on top and the main panel with card layout. When user taps a panel on the top a panel in the main area is shown.